# Logging to file vs. Logging to Database

Tags: mysql, django

I have a to-do list app ( using Django 1.5 and MySQL ) in which a task can be shared with another user. Thus, a user can have personal tasks and shared tasks. Shared tasks will be a fraction ( i guess around 30% of total tasks of a user )

For shared tasks, I want to keep a log so that users connected to the task can know who has done which changes.
For this, I'm thinking of keeping a log file for every shared task. Whenever any user makes a change, it'll be appended to that file.

My question is - Should I do it via file storage, or should I save it in database ?

Please note these points -

- Log will not be accessed frequently ( A file's log may be read 5-10 times max in an hour. )
- In an hour, there may be total >500 writes ( but for different files. So for a file there may be 10-50 max writes in an hour. So, concurrency is not a major issue. )
- I won't need to search or modify the data anyway after reading it.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file system can be thought of as a database as well, but here you are mainly comparing file system vs MySQL, a relational database. I would do this in the relational database for several reasons:

- The number one reason is for simplicity. You are already using a database. I would not introduce the added complexity of using files as well. Just add a new table and be done with it.
- Database permissions and file system permissions are often different, and you'll need to worry about both.
- This makes it easy to migration your application since you don't need to move files *and* database.
- You have not foreseen any filtering, yet, but your clients more than likely will request it in the future.
- In a database, you have much better control over performance. You can't really index a file system. Most file systems store the list of files in a file that must be scanned every time.
- Sharding in the database is more transparent than in the file system. It's difficult to spread files to multiple storage locations without changing the way you access them.

I don't see any benefits to storing on the file system if you already have a relational database set up.

Answer (score 2):

> so that users connected to the task can know who has done which changes

This changes the data in question from system-level logging to application-visible data.  As such, it probably belongs in the application's database.  This will also make it a lot easier to filter the log data for display.  For example, if you want to show all historical events for Item X then you can easily query a database table which has a foreign key relationship to the Items table.  Reading in that data from a file and filtering it manually would be unnecessarily difficult.

Side note: "audit data" or perhaps "history data" might be a better term, to distinguish it from system logging such as error logs.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference between what i need and logs. Regarding filtering, I won't need to filter the log or read portions of it at all. I just have to display it directly on the client-side. So, it's not a concern.